# Assign array of object content to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I'm trying to assign an array of objects to another array but when I created the new array and in others functions I change its value, the original array changes as well (which is not ok). Could I use another way?
This is an example: http ://codepen.io/Xiwi/pen/rLMbYp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to copy/clone the array so it will not be changed by reference.

If you have only *[Primitive Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values)* in the array you can do like this:

```
var test3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test2));
```

otherwise you need a recursive solution and to be more specific in your question.

Example:

```js
var test1 = [{name: 'test1'}];
var test2 = [{name: 'test2'}];
var test3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test2));

test3[0].name = 'test3';

// Open console
console.log('Test2: ',test2[0]); // Object {name: "test2"}
console.log('Test3: ',test3[0]); // Object {name: "test3"}
```

Comment: you don't have to serialize, I believe `[].splice(0,0, arr);` will do a copy of primitives

Comment: sorry `[].concat(arr)`

Comment: @kirinthos no. Like that you will have the same problem. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/jbL0vm9m/

Comment: uh I said array of primitives

Comment: @kirinthos, if you mean array of primitives yes, then you can use just `var test3 = test2.slice();` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jbL0vm9m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Objects are essentially references.  You must create a new object and assign the values of another object:

```
var test3 = [ Object.assign({}, test2[0]) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `.map` to copy one array of objects to another.

```
var test1 = [{name: 'test1'}];
var test2 = [{name: 'test2'}];
//var test3 = test2.slice(0); //doesn't work. objects are still references
var test3 = test2.map(function(obj){
  //return obj; //doesn't work. objects are still references
  var o={}; //create brand new object
  for(var prop in obj)
    o[prop]=obj[prop];//assign properties
  return  o;//works
});

test3[0].name = 'test3';

// Open console
console.log('Test2: ',test2[0]);
console.log('Test3: ',test3[0]);
```